# Вводное слово в конце придаточного предложения

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Нужны ли здесь дополнительные запятые?

> Как происходит обработка и передача данных в системе, которая стала смартом по Вашим словам?

Розенталь пишет: "Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не отделяется". Но здесь не оборот, а придаточное предложение... Как быть в этом случае?

Answer (score 3):

Ваша фраза не соответствует приведённому Вами пункту из Розенталя (§99 п. 5). Значит, **действует общее правило: вводные слова и словосочетания выделяются запятыми**.

Тем более что без запятой фраза приобретает другой смысл. Сравните:

**Поэтому Господь сказал: блаженны те, которые уверуют по вашим словам.** [Протоиерей Димитрий Смирнов. Проповеди (1984-1989)]

Как минимум, нужно поставить запятую.

**Как происходит обработка и передача данных в системе, которая стала смартом, по Вашим словам?**

Но этого недостаточно. Не совсем понятно, к чему относится вводное словосочетание - к основному или придаточному предложению.

Во избежание неоднозначности, я бы перестроил фразу:

**Как происходит обработка и передача данных в системе, которая, по Вашим словам, стала смартом?**

Answer (score 2):

Как происходит обработка и передача данных в системе, которая стала смартом, **по Вашим словам?**

В этом случае вводные слова должны обособляться **по общим правилам**, в то время как в случае обособленного оборота (позиция вводного слова в начале или в конце) они играют роль **присоединительного союза** и не обособляются.